# How to understand Singleton in c++?

Tags: c++, singleton

Please tell me why the singleton code below works? Every time When `Singleton::instance()` is called, an INSTANCE will be created, so are two INSTANCE supposed to be created in the following code?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
    private:
       Singleton() = default;

    public:
       static Singleton& instance()
       {
          static Singleton INSTANCE;
          return INSTANCE;
       }
};

int main()
{
    Singleton &s1 = Singleton::instance();
    Singleton &s2 = Singleton::instance();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). And [`using namespace std;` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: And I recommend you get [a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read and learn more about what `static` does.

Comment: Not sure why you think there would be two instances created. Do you know what [static](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) does in this context?

Comment: Do not learn something what [is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137975/1387438).

Comment: I know what `static` means, but each time when expression `static Singleton INSTANCE;` executed. Isn't different `INSTANCE` created?

Comment: @fizzbuzz No, looks like you don't fully understand whtat `static` means :) _"... are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration [...] On all further calls, the declaration is skipped."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about the [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static) keyword. It can have different meaning and here you have two of them:

```
   static Singleton& instance()
   // ^ ---------------------------- (1)
   {
      static Singleton INSTANCE;
      // ^ ------------------------- (2)
      return INSTANCE;
   }
```

The first `static` declares the method `instance` as a "class-method" (or simply "static method"). You can call the method without having an instance.

The second `static` declares that `INSTANCE` has static storage duration. That is: There is only one. It is initialized once and when you reenter the function you get the exact same instance.

Answer (score 2):

you can go line by line:

```
1. 
Singleton &s1 = Singleton::instance();
```

you call here the static method `instance()`, inside that method you see the line

```
 static Singleton INSTANCE;
```

the trick here is to understand that variables declared static inside a method will only declared once, no matter how many times you call the method after. So it creates the instance of `Singleton` and it gets returned

```
 2.
Singleton &s2 = Singleton::instance();
```

the second call will actually skip the delaration of INSTANCE and will return that immediatly.

for more clarifying you can put some meaningful messages in the constructor

something like

```
std::cout << "Contructor called!" << std::endl;
```

even better if you use a static variable as a counter just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time When Singleton::instance() is called, an INSTANCE will be created, so are two INSTANCE supposed to be created in the following code?

No. Only one instance is created.

> each time when expression static Singleton INSTANCE; executed. Isn't different INSTANCE created?

No.

> I know what static means

Evidently, you don't know what you think you know.